# Add comment character to lines in a StringBuffer

Tags: java, parsing, stringbuffer

I have a StringBuffer representing a file.
I would like to add comment characters at the beginning of (some of the) lines.
For example, if this is how my content looks like:

```
line  
line  
line  
line-to-comment  
line-to-comment  
line  
line
```

I would like to get the following results:

```
line  
line  
line  
#line-to-comment  
#line-to-comment  
line  
line
```

BTW, Our syntax doesn't allow multi lines comments (such as /** ... **/).
What would be the best approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

```
String uncommentedLines = myFile.substring(startIndex, endIndex);  
String commentedBlock = "#" + uncommentedLines.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), System.lineSeparator()+"#");  
myFile.replace(startIndex, endIndex, commentedBlock);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution probably is straightforward string manipulation.

```
StringBuffer sb = ....:
int pos = sb.indexOf("line-to-comment");
sb.insert(pos, "#");
```

In case you'll do this repeatedly, you'll need to check the character at pos-1 to be different from "#".

At least that's what I should do...